# Conditional type based on boolean flag in an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to type a function which returns one of two different types, depending on if a flag was passed in an options object or not.

Here is an attempt where TypeScript complains:

```
type Opts = { two?: boolean }

type LogFn<O> = O extends { two?: true }
   ? (a: string, b: string) => any
   : (a: string) => any

   function log(opts: Opts = {}): LogFn<Opts> {
      if (opts.two) {
      // Type '(a: any, b: any) => void' is not assignable to type
      // '(a: string) => any'.(2322)
      return (a, b) => { console.log("two: ", a, b) }
   } else {
      return (a) => { console.log("one: ", a) }
   }
}

const one = log()
const two = log({ two: true })

one("x")
// Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.(2554)
two("y", "z")
```

It seems like the expression `O extends { two?: true}` is always false. But the expression `{ two: true} extends { two?: true}` is always true and if I play around with that the empty object and a false value behave as they should. But it doesn't work with the generic variable which of course is what I need.

[TypeScript Playground link for the above example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=21&pln=5&pc=24#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwGcoF4oG8rAO4HsD8AXFAEY44A2EAhgHZQC+AUI6JFADI4DmAYjQDwwAfClhQIAD2AQaAEyQZs+IsABOAV2hMoOvFAAUVIgjUBLGlwA0JY2YsBKFCNohGOqEUO3V5ro+TONK6MAGbqNADGwKY4dOTcguJSMvKw8EiocIhC+gD6OOmEsPZEnLwCwgDcoeFRMXHceQWIRVkIJQZGUCY+FtbERT2+-oEg6G46EbEmUM0IRG2i+elQAD6r6No6piEGcwB0So5oE+5QqhDA6qp0hv0j6FBTNAgUEPvxXPoAREpE39YqPcGFBTvRxOQENATmcdBcrjdOg8MM9XpQPo1vrEIP9AY4tgxGExGKjgLMaNBUJ99PYSdMyUpRNTFLgVBotLTGNifhJvrSlD8QACoN8AF58oA)

Comment: I would recommend not naming the type parameter the same as another type.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks! I've updated my code example to name it differently, while also harmonizing with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your use case is, but the problem with your code is that `log()` needs to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function if you'd like the type of the output to depend on the type of the input.  So the signature needs to look like `log<O extends Opts>(opts?: O): LogFn<O>`;

Once you do this, since the return type of `log()` will itself be generic, the compiler won't be able to verify that the specific return values inside the implementation match it, even though you are checking `opts.two`.  It's a known issue that control flow analysis (like checking `opts.two`) does not narrow the type of generic type parameters (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995)).  Since the compiler will be unable to verify something that you know, it's reasonable to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress compiler warnings.  Or, you can do the equivalent of an assertion: give the function a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) signature, and have the implementation signature be wide enough to prevent errors.

It would look something like this:

```
function log<O extends Opts = Opts>(_opts?: O): LogFn<O>;
function log(_opts?: Opts): (a: string, b?: string) => any {
   const opts: Opts = _opts || {}
   if (opts.two) {
      return (a, b) => { console.log("two: ", a, b) }
   } else {
      return (a) => { console.log("one: ", a) }
   }
}
```

That compiles without errors.  Note that I have made the parameter `_opts` which is either `O` or missing (and hence `undefined`), and in the case where it is missing, the compiler will fall back to the generic default of `Opts`.  Then inside the function I make `const opts: Opts = _opts || {}` to make sure it's always defined.  This should behave the same as your original default function parameter, but my code plays more nicely with using a generic `O` instead of the concrete `Opts`.

Anyway, now the following behaves as you expect:

```
const one = log()
const two = log({ two: true })

one("x")
two("y", "z")
```

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwGcoF4oG8rAO4HsD8AXFAEY44A2EAhgHZQC+AUI6JFADI4DmAYjQDwwAfClhQIAD2AQaAEyQZs+IsABOAV2hMoOvFAAUVIgjUBLGlwA0JY2YsBKFCNohGOqEUO3V5ro+TONK6MAGbqNADGwKY4dOTcguJSMvKw8EiocIhC+gD6OOmEsPZEnLwCwgDcoeFRMXHceQWIRVkIJQZGUCY+FtbERT2+-oEg6G46EbEmUM0IRG2i+elQAD6r6No6piEGcwB0So5oE+5QqhDA6qp0hv0j6FBTNAgUEPvxXPoAREpE39YqPcGFBTvRxOQENATmcdBcrjdOg8MM9XpQPo1vrEIP9AY4tgxGExGKjgLMaNBUJ99PYSdMyUpRNTFLgVBotLTGNifhJvrSlD8QACoN8AF58oA)

Comment: Awesome answer! What does `O extends Opts = Opts` do? What's the `generic default of Opts`?